# Unable to find vcvarsall.bat (Unsolved for 2022 version, Python)

Tags: python, visual-c++, installation, error-handling, pgzero

I've been trying to instsall pgzero library for python, but however it keeps giving me an error:
"unable to find vcvarsall.bat "
I have been searching over StackOverflow, it shows up how to fix it for 2017 version by installing Microsoft building tools, i did download them, but it is still not installing. Is there any suggestion on how to solve the problem? I have a pip I simply have written

> pip install pgzero

[image: picture with an error]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots - especially unreadable ones. Copy/Paste the terminal output into your question as text. See [ask].

Comment: Alriight, thanks for telling me, Its pretty much the same where my arrow is pointing, Unable to find vcvarsall.bat.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this command worked, first install pygame like this:

`pip install pygame --pre`

then install pgzero

`pip install pgzero --pre`